# не отображается RecyclerView в ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-viewpager

значится, я пытаюсь в viewpager2 отобразить ресайклвью, во фрагменте, однако дело не в иьюпаджер ибо его я проверил текствью, и он отображался

код фрагмента
до(смотрите комментарии):

```
class tabfragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tabfragment) {
    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentTabfragmentBinding::bind)
    private val bd by lazy { notesdb.notedbfunc(requireActivity()).gdao()}
    private val noterep : NoteRepository by lazy { repositoryimp(bd) }
    private val notesdata by lazy { noterep.getnoteslived() }
    private val notes = mutableListOf<note>()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabfragment,container,false)
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.recyclerviewitem.adapter = recyclerviewclass()
    binding.recyclerviewitem.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
    var noteadapter = recyclerviewclass()
    notesdata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    println(it)
        it.forEach { i ->
            if(i.deleted == false && i.archived == false){
                notes.add(i)
            }
        }
        noteadapter.update(notes)
        notes.clear()
    }


}
}
```

после:

```
class tabfragment : Fragment() {
private val bd by lazy { notesdb.notedbfunc(requireActivity()).gdao()}
private val noterep : NoteRepository by lazy { repositoryimp(bd) }
private val notesdata by lazy { noterep.getnoteslived() }
private val notes = mutableListOf<note>()
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabfragment,container,false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    var recyclerview = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewitem)
    recyclerview.adapter = recyclerviewclass()
    recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
    var noteadapter = recyclerviewclass()
    notesdata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    println(it)
        it.forEach { i ->
            if(i.deleted == false && i.archived == false){
                notes.add(i)
            }
        }
        noteadapter.update(notes)
        notes.clear()
    }


}
}
```

ресайклвью, я до этого использовал также во фрагменте и он работал,во вьюпадгер перестал

```
class recyclerviewclass() :
RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerviewclass.MyViewHolder>() {
private val array = mutableListOf<note>()
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun update(newlist : List<note>){
    array.clear()
    array.addAll(newlist)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
var layouts = mutableListOf<FrameLayout>()
var onbuttonclickfordelete: ((note) -> Unit)? = null
var onbuttonlongclick : ((note) -> Unit)? = null
var onbuttonclick : ((note) -> Unit)? = null
var arrnotes = mutableListOf<note>()
var bool = true
fun invisiblecheckboxs(){
    layouts.forEach {
        it.checkBox.isChecked = false
        it.checkBox.isVisible = false
    }
    arrnotes.clear()
}
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val layout = itemView.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.layoutnote)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitem, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "SuspiciousIndentation")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, i: Int) {

    layouts.add(holder.layout)
    holder.layout.namenote.setText(array[i].namenote)
    holder.layout.note.setText(array[i].note)
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener {
        if(arrnotes.size >= 1){
            bool = true
            arrnotes.find {
                array[i] == it
            }?.let {
                bool = false
                arrnotes.remove(it)
                if (arrnotes.size == 0){
                    layouts.forEach { i ->
                        i.namenote.width = i.namenote.width + i.checkBox.width
                        i.note.width = i.note.width + i.checkBox.width
                        i.checkBox.isVisible = false
                    }
                }
                holder.layout.checkBox.isChecked = false
                onbuttonclickfordelete?.invoke(it)
            }
            if (bool) {
                arrnotes.add(array[i])
                holder.layout.checkBox.isChecked = true
                onbuttonlongclick?.invoke(array[i])
            }

        }
        else{
            onbuttonclick?.invoke(array[i])
        }
    }
    holder.layout.setOnLongClickListener {
        bool = true
        arrnotes.find {
            array[i] == it
        }?.let {
            bool = false
            arrnotes.remove(it)
            if (arrnotes.size == 0){
                layouts.forEach { i ->
                    i.namenote.width = i.namenote.width + i.checkBox.width
                    i.note.width = i.note.width + i.checkBox.width
                    i.checkBox.isVisible = false
                }
                holder.layout.namenote.width = holder.layout.namenote.width - holder.layout.checkBox.width
                holder.layout.note.width = holder.layout.note.width - holder.layout.checkBox.width
            }
            holder.layout.checkBox.isChecked = false
            onbuttonclickfordelete?.invoke(it)
        }
        if (bool) {
            arrnotes.add(array[i])
            if (arrnotes.size == 1){
                layouts.forEach { i ->
                    i.namenote.width = i.namenote.width - i.checkBox.width
                    i.note.width = i.note.width - i.checkBox.width
                    i.checkBox.isVisible = true
                }
            }
            holder.layout.checkBox.isChecked = true
            onbuttonlongclick?.invoke(array[i])
        }
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return array.size
}
}
```

обьяснение причины ошибки в коментариях к ответу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас много странного в коде. Очень сбивает несоблюдение конвенций именования - классы должны быть с большой буквы, например. Поверхностно видно 3 проблемы -

1. Вы в onCreateView одну разметку возвращаете, а в onViewCreated другую используете (через `binding`). Надо выбрать что-то одно - оба варианта вместе не имеют смысла и не будут работать. Странно, что вообще не падает.
2. Не факт, что проблема, но layoutManager лучше до адаптера устанавливать.
3. Вы разные экземпляры адаптера используете. В recyclerviewitem один устанавливаете, а меняете потом другой.

Comment: я не очень понял про 1, там вроде одна разметка и в возврате и в байндинг, 2 - учту, но дело не в этом, проверял, 3 - тоже не понял, вы имеете ввиду что я в myviewholder добавляю layotnote, а в oncreateviewholder recyclerviewitem, если да то это один и тот же файл просто лайоут layoutnote находиться в recyclerviewitem, так просто удобнее

Comment: 1. Сложно придумать как объяснить) Кажется, вы думаете, что указав один и тот же файл разметки по разному в разных местах вы получите один и тот же объект. Это не так. У вас, по идее, отображается один экземпляр разметки, а настраивать вы пытаетесь другой. 3. Тут, похоже, у вас та же ошибка - адаптеров у вас 2 - один вы в ресайклер поставили, а другой обнвляете. Они никак не связаны. Вам, кажется, надо разобраться что такое класс и что такое его экземпляр.

Comment: 3. да меня это тоже смутило, но я подумал раз работает как надо трогать не буду, но учту спасибо. 1. не могли бы вы написать для чего прописывается разметка в class tabfragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tabfragment), если не сложно. Итакже может вы заметили ошибку по которой могла бы ресайклервью не отображаться

Comment: О, я даже не заметил, что у вас, получается, 3 разных способа для разметки) Я думаю, что ошибка в этом. (но может быть и в другом месте, у вас много в коде странного). Начните с того, чтобы оставить один способ работы с разметкой, самый древний и простой - удалите аргумент из конструктора фрагмента, удалите переменную `binding` и везде используйте что-то типа `val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId)`. Так можно будет исключить проблему использоания разных экземпляров одной и той же разметки.

Comment: обьясните пожалуйста для чего, пишется class tabfragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tabfragment), и дело не в том что отписали сверху, я проверил, не могли бы вы поискать более серьезные ошибки

Comment: 1. Посмотрите [доку](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html) - там сказано, что разметка указанная в конструкторе фрагмента будет возвращена из `onCreateView` метода. Т.е вы либо используете этот конструктор или сами возвращаете загруженную через `LayoutInflater` вьюху или используете ViewBinding. Но только что-то одно (sic!). Вы же все три способа смешали - оно не должно работать. Я не могу быть уверен, что вы всё вышеописанное учли. Покажите обновлённый код с учётом исправления путаницы в том какую разметку и как вы отобразить пытаетесь.

Comment: 2. То что вы с адаптером делаете примерно на 100% ошибочно. У вас в RecyclerView адаптер с пустым массивом, а потом вы из БД получаете данные и передаёте их в другой адаптер. В итоге RecyclerView никаких данных для отображения не получает.

Comment: готово, сделал.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `var noteadapter = recyclerviewclass()` на `var noteadapter = recyclerview.adapter as recyclerviewclass`. Если не поможет - попробуйте убедиться, что фрагмент вообще отображается. Как я понят он у вас во ViewPager. Попробуйте из `onViewCreated` что-то в логи вывести и проверить - будет ли. Может быть мы всё это время вообще не ту проблему решаем)

Comment: да вы были правы, все починилось, большое спасибо

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - вы можете его "верным" отметить, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: я тут другую тему пересоздал(осмотренную вами) с обновленным кодом и лучшим расписыванием проблемы, тоже на тему RecyclerView, не могли бы вы просмотреть, может тоже поймете в чем проблема